# Why is the strong CP term $ \theta \frac{g^2}{32 \pi^2} G_{\mu \nu}^a \tilde{G}^{a, \mu \nu}$ never considered for $SU(2)$ or $U(1)$ interactions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, quantum-chromodynamics, strong-force, axion

The Lagrangian one would write down naively for QCD is invariant under CP, which is in agreement with all experiments.

Nevertheless, if we add the term

\begin{equation}
 \theta \frac{g^2}{32 \pi^2} G_{\mu \nu}^a \tilde{G}^{a, \mu \nu},
\end{equation}

where $\tilde{G}^{a,\mu \nu} = \frac{1}{2} \epsilon^{\mu \nu \rho \sigma} G^a_{ \rho \sigma}$ is the dual field strength tensor to the Lagrangian, QCD isn't CP invariant anymore. This is known as the **strong CP problem**

- Why do we need to consider this term in QCD, and why is it never mentioned in weak- or electromagnetic interactions? (In the literature I was only able to find the nebulous statement that this is because of the topological structure of the QCD ground state)
- This term isn't invariant under parity transformations, so why isn't there a **strong P problem**, too?

Comment: for your first question see http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27462/

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/91535/12813

Answer (score 6):

You are asking four questions, whose answers are routinely provided in textbooks.

- We consider it in QCD since there is no fundamental reason to exclude it, and topological configurations such as instantons, etc.. might well generate it in an effective low energy theory: the rule of thumb is that anything that is not prohibited has to emerge out of the workings of QFT.
- In pure EM theory, you can quickly convince yourself it integrates out to a surface term--a total divergence.
- Electroweak theory *already violates* P and CP at substantial levels, by dint of chiral couplings and the CKM matrix, so no further ultraweak effects due to such a term would stick out as they do in the strong interactions which lack such. If such effects are (so far) unobservable in QCD, despite  sticking out like a sore thumb, they would be resolutely unobservable in the weak interactions, a fortiori. Nevertheless, [speculative work](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0550321394903921), indeed [a cottage industry](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370269312006065),  [cf](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370269314002329) , has entertained the question. Finally, it is not clear the effects of such a topological term cannot be rotated/hidden into the CP-phases of the CKM matrix.
- Who says there is no *P* violation in it? The [EDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_electric_dipole_moment) certainly breaks both *P* and *T*   (~ *CP*).

Comment: About your second point. I think even in QCD it is a total divergence. @CosmasZachos

Comment: Of course! It is *always a topological term*. I offered QED to let you see the point quickly.